# Нумерация строк в зависимости от значения столбца

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица со столбцами `group` и `flag`. Нужно пронумеровать их строки для каждой группы (`group`), получить столбец `number`. Если флаг (`flag`) равен `1`, то номер строки (`number`) увеличивается на `1`, если флаг равен `0`, то номер строки будет равен последнему номеру строки с флагом `1`. `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 - 14.0.3445.2 (X64)`

| group | flag | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: А что определяет порядок исходных строк? физический - не подходит. Нужен точный ORDER BY, который располагает записи именно в указанном порядке. *Если флаг (flag) равен 1, то номер строки (number) увеличивается на 1, если флаг равен 0, то номер строки будет равен последнему номеру строки с флагом 1.* `SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY [???])`

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл добавить столбец cur_time (Время). Сейчас отсортированы по времени в порядке возрастания. Спасибо за SUM(flag) - самое то! Как это сам не догадался!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, SUM(flag)OVER(PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY cur_time
    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
  )[number]
FROM [Table]
```

1. Убедитесь, что пара [`group`] + `cur_time` - уникальна
2. Не забудьте добавить `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`,
   По умолчанию используется `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, что работает медленнее, т.к. приводит к спулу окна.